# The parameterized query is truncated and parameters are lost

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sqlparameter, executescalar

I have a piece of code:

```
command.Parameters.Clear();
command.Parameters.Add(ownerUserIDParam);
command.Parameters.Add(buddyUserIDParam);
command.Parameters.Add(timestampParam);
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GiftID", giftID));
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GiftStatus", (byte)GiftStatusEnum.wait));
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO SentGefts (OwnerUserID, BuddyUserID, CreateTS, GiftID, Status, AcceptRejectTS, ParentEntityType, ParentEntityID) VALUES (@OwnerUserID, @BuddyUserID, @TS, @GiftID, @GiftStatus, @TS, 0 ,0);";
command.CommandText += "SELECT @@IDENTITY;";
result.GiftInstanceID = long.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

And I recieve: The parameterized query '(@OwnerUserID int,@BuddyUserID int,@TS datetime,@GiftID int,@Gif' expects the parameter '@GiftStatus', which was not supplied.

Note: '(@OwnerUserID int,@BuddyUserID int,@TS datetime,@GiftID int,@Gif' is truncated and is exactly 64 symbols... And it just ends on an unfinished paramter name 'Gif' (and the exception is also about this parameter).

Why it can't see my parameter?

UPD:
If I replce adding the last parameter (@GiftStatus) this way:
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GiftStatus", (byte)GiftStatusEnum.wait);

This way things start working. But I just can't figure out what's wrong with .Add(new SqlParamter());

Comment: Just a note, ExecuteScalar returns proper data types wrapped in an object. You are likely being given an `int` or a `long` so there is no need to do `.ToString` with the `Parse`.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214628/insert-bytes-array-into-varbinarymax-record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to supply all parameters along with their names.
You'd better use `Paramteres.AddWithValue(...)`.
So:

```
Parameters.AddWithValue("@OwnerUserID", ...);
Parameters.AddWithValue("@BuddyUserID", ...);
Parameters.AddWithValue("@TS", ...);
Parameters.AddWithValue("@GiftID", ...);
Parameters.AddWithValue("@GiftStatus", ...);
```

Comment: Doesn't this line do the trick?
command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@GiftStatus", (byte)GiftStatusEnum.wait));

Comment: you are combining the 2 things in your code (normal value and SqlParameter). AddWithValue is much easier to read and use...

Comment: Actually I only add SqlParameter type values (ownerUserIDParam, ... - those are all of SqlParameter type).

Comment: But if I change just line with GiftStatus parameter to AddWithValue way, things start working... Thank you, I am very happy with working code, but I just want to figure out what's wrong with .Add(new SqlParameter());

Comment: Also works fine this way: command.Parameters.Add("@GiftStatus", SqlDbType.TinyInt).Value = (byte)GiftStatusEnum.wait;

Comment: The only point I could stick to is the fact, that sometimes when I cast to byte, SqlParamter constructor fails to determine SqlDbType correctly. So it is better to explicitly specify SqlDbType for parameters.

Comment: I was unable to make the database accept an string when sent as AddWithValue. It always complained that the parameter wasn't supplied. I then used `cmd.Parameters.Add("@error_msg", System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256); cmd.Parameters["@error_msg"].Value = error_msg;` which made the database accept the parameter (unless it is null in which case I have to supply DBNull.Value).

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing the following command before ExecuteScalar()

```
command.CommandText += "SELECT @@IDENTITY;";
command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
result.GiftInstanceID = long.Parse(command.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
```

Comment: SqlCommand.CommandType Property: "One of the CommandType values. The default is **Text**." ~ [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: Although your problem is somewhere else, you should keep that command anyway.

Comment: Are you running SQL profiler? How do you know the SQL is being chopped off at 64 symbols(characters)?

Comment: Please copy and paste the exception

Comment: The parameterized query '(@OwnerUserID int,@BuddyUserID int,@TS datetime,@GiftID int,@Gif' expects the parameter '@GiftStatus', which was not supplied.